# how to get ldap certificate bypass the mutual certification using Java

Tags: java, ldap, certificate, jndi, starttls

I'm writing a project that could get Ldap certificate from a remote server. It works fine for the general mode when the server does not require mutual certification. But when I try a server that requires mutual certification, it fails. Here is the code:

```
    String serverSpec = null;
    boolean enableAnonSuites = false;
    boolean isTracing = false;

    // Try and parse command line arguments.
    try {

        serverSpec = "ldap://10.47.16.60:389";
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        trace(true,e.toString());
        usage();
        return;
    }

    try {

        // Create a SocketFactory that will be given to LDAP for 
        // building SSL sockets
        MySocketFactory msf = new MySocketFactory(isTracing,
                enableAnonSuites);

        // Set up environment for creating initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");


        // Must use the name of the server that is found in its certificate
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
                serverSpec
                );

        // Create initial context
        trace(isTracing,"Creating new Ldapcontext");
        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        // Start 
        trace(isTracing,"Performing StartTlsRequest");
        StartTlsResponse tls = null;

        try {
            tls = (StartTlsResponse)ctx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
        }
        catch (NamingException e) {
            trace(true,"Unable to establish SSL connection:\n"
                    +e);
            return;
        }


        // The default JSSE implementation will compare the hostname of
        // the server with the hostname in the server's certificate, and
        // will not proceed unless they match.  To override this behaviour,
        // you have to provide your own HostNameVerifier object.  The 
        // example below simply bypasses the check

        tls.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Negotiate SSL on the connection using our own SocketFactory
        trace(isTracing,"Negotiating SSL");
        SSLSession sess = null;
        sess = tls.negotiate(msf);

        X509Certificate[] cert = sess.getPeerCertificateChain();
```

The exception information is as follows: "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal error", and it happens at the "negotiate" method. And I analyzed the wireshark trace information and am sure this is because the server requires mutual certification. Right now, I'm wondering if there are certain class that is in the com.sun.jndi.ldap package that could be useful for this problem. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If there was such a class in the JDK it would be insecure. If the server requires a client certificate and won't operate without one, you have to provide one. That's the point of the exception.

Comment: +1 for emphasis. You cannot bypass mutual authentication if it's required by the server.

Comment: Thanks. I think I haven't made my question clear. I mean, because the ultimate goal is to get the certificate and I can see from the wireshack trace that the server has already sent the certificate to me(mutual certification means that the server sends the certificate to the client and client response with its certificate). And the client do get the certificate before the handshake completes. So, the problem is, I didn't find a way to get the certificate even if the server has already sent it to me. Is there a way to get the certificate in Java before the handshake completes?